# emulating ionic really slow even on genymotion just using the "tabs" example

Tags: android, genymotion

i'm trying to test my ionic app on genymotion but it's very slow (animations take up to 2 seconds to play, transitions are laggy)

I could not find a solution so i tried creating a test project from scratch to see if it worked smoothly on genymotion. I tried just running these commands on the command line to build a new example project.

```
     ionic start myApp tabs
     ionic platform android
     ionic run android
```

after that the example app gets started on genymotion, but it's still very slow. is this normal?

Answer (score 9):

I'm answering my own question hoping that it will be helpful to someone in the future.

After testing on a real device I discovered that apparently genymotion does not work well when emulating cordova apps (this might have something to do with the webview version genymotion uses, but i dont know), and android's SDK emulator is just horrible and unusable.

I tested my app on a real device and it works OK, so the emulation was not representative of the actual performance, not even using genymotion that has been known to be very fast, at least for hybrid apps in the current version

In the end testing on a real device seems to be the only way to be sure.

Comment: Hey. I have the latest Genymotion, nodejs, ionic (v2) - and it was shockingly slow/unusable on Genymotion. Installed Android Studio, and used the emulator through that, worked, and was fast, very responsive.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, I was wondering why it was so slow on genymotion and was starting to doubt this framework.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found is the following

1. Install "Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image" for your preferred SDK version (I'm using 6.0.0)
2. Create a new AVD with the following settings:

   - Target -> Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 23
   - CPU/ABI -> Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
   - Memory Option -> RAM -> 1024    *(too much ram causes the emulator not to start)*
   - Emulation Options -> Use Host GPU -> **Checked**

From my experience, this was the best performing emulator. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sdk version 4.2 , it is still better than 4.4 for now to run ionic in genymotion.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3619